# Call function from outside javascript file wait until class is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file that's placed on a client's website, structured like:

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.settings = null;
        this.customProps = null;
    }

    setProps(props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
           this.customProps = props;
        }
        
        this.settings.customProps = this.customProps;
    }
}

window.Example = new Example();
```

This link to this file is injected in the `<head>`, much like Google Analytics etc work.

Then from the page, I'd like the client to be able to optionally set custom properties:

```
Example.setProps({ foo: 'bar' });
```

The problem is that I have no control over where that is placed. So I noticed that what could happen is that the code is called before the javascript file is loaded, resulting in the following error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.settings.customProps = this.customProps')`.

I assume I have to build in a check in setProps that checks whether the class `Example` is ready? And then if it's not wait until it is and then set the props?

Comment: You can have your JavaScript run at a certain time, like on page load, etc.

Comment: I'd like the javascript file to be loaded after the page is done loading to not impact performance of the client's website. That's why I want to try to find a solutions as is described in the answer. Is that possible?